# Can you password restrict access to certaion projects with Cruisecontrol.net?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I would like to give access to a subset of projects to a user in cc.net. Is it possible to restrict access to some projects in cc.net?

Alternatively, is it possible to have a second cc.net installation on the same machine?

Comment: No, other than using windows security.. CC.Net relies on windows permissions. The question arises: "why would you want to?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in version 1.5 only however.

[CC.NET Security](http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Security)

Comment: Do you know where there is any documentation on this? The best I have found is http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Scenario+One… but I does not tell you how to add the security block to the cc.net config